Shot fired to be drawn toward cursor crosshair (JS)
Alright, so I'm building a simple shooter game. And i've gotten the shooting to work. I've been wrestling with the logic for the shot to be drawn towards the crosshair, that is the mouse position, for quite some time now.
I am sucessfully tracking the mouseposition on the game area. I've established the shot being fired from the character. And I've managed to get the shot to go towards the aim. However, the shot when being fired towards the X,Y of the crosshair coordinates, it's now taking a straight left, and then a straight right, instead of going diagonally. The shots also now stay left behind on the map and are not being cleared as they were before.
I've been staring myself blind on this, and would appreciate any input in the logic. What am I missing here? I really want to figure this out with as little help as possible. So any hint would be very appreciated!
This is my logic for updating the shotPosition after firing as of writing this:
`updateShotPosition() {  
        for (let i = 0; i < this.shots.length; i++) {
            if (this.shots[i].isActiveShot) {
                if (this.shots[i].startY > this.shots[i].endY) {
                    this.shots[i].startY -= 25;  
                }
                if (this.shots[i].startY < this.shots[i].endY) {
                    this.shots[i].startY += 25;                       
                }
                if (this.shots[i].startX < this.shots[i].endX) {
                    this.shots[i].startX += 25;
                }
                if (this.shots[i].startX > this.shots[i].endX) {
                    this.shots[i].startX -= 25;
                }
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fillRect(this.shots[i].startX + 20, this.shots[i].startY- 10, 5, 5);        
            }
        }
    }`

I'm expecting for the shot to be draw towards the crosshair in a single motion, and not taking two paths to reach the crosshair.

Update: I realize that the shots are being stopped at the crosshair position since I only increment och decrement the position untill its at the crosshair position.
